Con javascript (testing), usar input usuario en terminal y lograr 100% coverage
Soy novata con javascript y no consigo resolver un ejercicio que necesito entregar... Este sería su enunciado:

" Crea un programa que pida un valor de tamaño de array por input y
después el número del cuál se van a obtener múltiplos y devuelva un
array con el tamaño puesto de múltiplos de ese número (2, 4 => [4, 8]) ".

Lo que me está costando es que el usuario tiene que introducir por terminal los dos inputs, cosa que hago a través de una función, PERO luego esa función no pasa el coverage con jest.  Os muestro el código del archivo .js:
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

function get_multiples(size, base_number) {
  if (size <= 0 || base_number < 0 || isNaN(size) || isNaN(base_number)) {
    throw new Error('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  }
  const multiples = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    multiples.push(base_number * i);
  }
  return multiples;
}

function interact_with_user() {
  const size = parseInt(prompt('Enter the size of the array you want: '));
  const base_number = parseInt(prompt('Enter the base number you want to generate its multiples:'));

  try {
    const result = get_multiples(size, base_number);
    console.log(`Multiples Array: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

if (require.main === module) {
  interact_with_user();
}

module.exports = {
    get_multiples,
};

Este es el archivo de testing. Pero la cobertura es mala solo el 50% de las functions.
    const { get_multiples } = require('./calculate_multiples');

describe('get_multiples', () => {
  test('Must return an array with the correct multiples', () => {
    expect(get_multiples(3, 2)).toEqual([2, 4, 6]);
    expect(get_multiples(4, 3)).toEqual([3, 6, 9, 12]);
  });

  test('Must return an error if the array size is 0', () => {
    expect(() => get_multiples(0, 2)).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  });

  test('Must return an error if the size o base number is a negative number', () => {
    expect(() => get_multiples(-1, 2)).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
    expect(() => get_multiples(3, -2)).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  });

  test('Must return an array with 1 multiple if the size is 1', () => {
    expect(get_multiples(1, 5)).toEqual([5]);
  });

  test('Must return an error if size or base number are empty', () => {
    expect(() => get_multiples()).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  });
});


dices que: Lo que me está costando es que el usuario tiene que introducir por terminal los dos inputs, cosa que hago a través de una función supongo que te refieres a  interact_with_user y luego dices PERO luego esa función no pasa el coverage con jest. pero en el test no aparece esa función

Gracias Yussef, creo que eso es lo que me ocurre. No sé como pasar la función a los test. (mockeandola, encapsulándola, como nos dice el profe), estoy aprendiendo ...

Lo que tiene que testear es la función  interact_with_user. Mockea la función prompt para que no requiera realmente interactuar con los usuarios y juega con los posibles valores correctos e incorrectos de entrada.

Has de hacer un Mock de los prompts para simular los inputs del usuario.
Aqui tienes el script con la librería de los prompts modificada.
Esto te da un 100% de coverage:
const prompts = require('prompts');

function get_multiples(size, base_number) {
  if (size <= 0 || base_number < 0 || isNaN(size) || isNaN(base_number)) {
    throw new Error('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  }
  const multiples = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    multiples.push(base_number * i);
  }
  return multiples;
}

function interact_with_user() {
  prompts([
    {
      type: 'number',
      name: 'size',
      message: 'Enter the size of the array you want:',
    }, {
      type: 'number',
      name: 'base_number',
      message: 'Enter the base number you want to generate its multiples:',
    }]).then(input => {
    try {
      const result = get_multiples(input.size, input.base_number);
      console.log(`Multiples Array: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  get_multiples,
  interact_with_user,
};

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (require.main === module) interact_with_user();

calculate_multiples.test.js
const {get_multiples, interact_with_user} = require('./calculate_multiples');
const prompts = require('prompts');

jest.mock('prompts');

describe('get_multiples', () => {
  test('Must return an array with the correct multiples', () => {
    expect(get_multiples(3, 2)).toEqual([2, 4, 6]);
    expect(get_multiples(4, 3)).toEqual([3, 6, 9, 12]);
  });

  test('Must return an error if the array size is 0', () => {
    expect(() => get_multiples(0, 2)).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  });

  test('Must return an error if the size o base number is a negative number', () => {
    expect(() => get_multiples(-1, 2)).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
    expect(() => get_multiples(3, -2)).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  });

  test('Must return an array with 1 multiple if the size is 1', () => {
    expect(get_multiples(1, 5)).toEqual([5]);
  });

  test('Must return an error if size or base number are empty', () => {
    expect(() => get_multiples()).toThrow('The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  });
});

describe('interact_with_user', () => {
  afterAll(() => jest.restoreAllMocks());
  test('User must insert correct size and base_number values', async () => {
    prompts.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      size: 3,
      base_number: 2,
    });
    const consoleMock = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation();
    await interact_with_user();
    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Multiples Array: [2,4,6]');
  });
  test('Must return an error if user insert invalid values', async () => {
    prompts.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      size: 0,
      base_number: 2,
    });
    const consoleMock = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation();
    await interact_with_user();
    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error: The array size must be greater than 0 and base number must be greater or equal than 0');
  });
});

coverage:
 PASS  ./calculate_multiples.test.js
  get_multiples
    ✓ Must return an array with the correct multiples (1 ms)
    ✓ Must return an error if the array size is 0 (3 ms)
    ✓ Must return an error if the size o base number is a negative number
    ✓ Must return an array with 1 multiple if the size is 1
    ✓ Must return an error if size or base number are empty (1 ms)
  interact_with_user
    ✓ User must insert correct size and base_number values
    ✓ Must return an error if user insert invalid values (1 ms)

------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                    | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files               |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |
 calculate_multiples.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |
------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       7 passed, 7 total


Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Puede que para ti sea claro lo que hace, pero para otros, no. Lee [answer].

Ufff, que pasada zguillez. Muchísimas gracias. Voy a probar todo e ir poco a poco entendiendo mis fallos. Qué vaya muy bien!

/* istanbul ignore next */es para que Jest ignore la siguiente línea. Ya que esa línea de código sólo sirve para ejecutar el programa y no la podrás añadir a un test, con lo que te bajaría inecesariamente el coverage.
